# Switching activities loses functionality

Tags: java, android, activity-lifecycle

I have an app that consists of 3 Activities

- MainActivity
- CalculatorActivity
- InformationActivity

My **MainActivity** has a confirm button that onClick starts the **CalculatorActivity** and everything is done correct and working as intended.

**CalculatorActivity** has 2 buttons, one  calculateButton that checks  something and shows a message and a learnMorebutton that starts the **InformationActivity**.

When I am on the 
**CalculatorActivity** for the first time everything is fine and working.Pressing the  learnMoreButton navigates me to the **InformationActivity**.That activity looks like this :

**InformationActivity**:

```
 goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switchActivity();
        }
    });
}
public void switchActivity(){
    final Intent intentObj = new Intent(this,CalculatorActivity.class);
    startActivity(intentObj);
}
```

A goBack button that gets me back to **CalculatorActivity**.Going back seems to break the  functionality.Although the layout is there and everything looks as it should be, pressing the buttons (calculateButton,learnMoreButton) does nothing.

**CalculatorActivity** :

`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
        final Button  calculateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculateId);
        final Button learnMoreButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.learnMoreButtonId);`

there are some more TextView and EditText that dont show up here but you get the point.Some more methods that do the calculations ,getters and setters.

This method
`public void switchActivity(){
        final Intent intentObj = new Intent(this,Information_activity.class);
        startActivity(intentObj);
    }`

But I am not using **onResume()** , **onPause()** or any methods from the lifecycle apart from **onCreate()**.

From some search that I have done I found out that I am doing something wrong with how I manage the activity lifecycle but I still can't find the solution.The dev documents didn't help me that much and a post with kinda the same problem as mine is old.

My question is, how the navigation from **InformationActivity** to **CalculatorActivity** should be done, so the functionality doesn't break when **CalculatorActivity** comes back to interact with the user.Which method should be called **onResume()**? , **onRestart()**? and how should it look like?

Thanks anyone who is willing to help.

P.S: As I mentioned , I have read the documents for the lifecycle of an Activity but I haven't found the solution.

Comment: if you explicitly have buttons that start new activities every time they are pressed and you don't wanna use the back button even while going back in the flow  you might wanna try finishing your activity before starting a new one . You can do that using the finish() after the call to startActivity(intentObj)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        InformationActivity.this.finish();
    }
 });
}
```

Instead of saying where to go back, you can just finish the activity and it will automatically switch you to the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

instead of starting new activity everytime, finish the informationactivity.

```
goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        finish();
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You are creating too much activities  moving going back and forth this way.  You can use either destroy the activity with **finish();** or you can also go back to previous activity using **onBackPressed();**

```
goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this should be hierarchical so you need to declare that those sub activities are child activities for this to work nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I think your activities are hierarchical thus you should be able to do the following from your main calculator activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i);
```

Your back button add this code:

```
goBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        setResult(Result.OK);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are all suggesting the same thing.Adding

`Information_Activity.this.finish()`

fixed the broken functionality , though you are all correct I can pick only one answer.

Thanks